# How can I join two objects together in order to shade as one object?

Tags: shaders, linked-data

I have two objects I created separately then put them both on the same file and wanted to join them, creating one object. I tried selecting both then pressing the join button. That worked for object mode and edit mode but when when I try shading the new object it only does each individual object as if they weren't joined.

Here is what it looks like when I try to shade them together, you can see the top part isn't shaded while the bottom part is:[image: Here is what it looks like when I try to shade them together, you can see the top part isn't shaded while the bottom part is.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "normal" behaviour.

If you look at the objects material you will see two materials.

[image]

Now enter Edit-mode by pressing TAB, select the first material and hit on "Select" and you will see:

[image]

So all these faces are assigned to that material.

You can change that easily by e.g. press A to select all and then hit assign.

Then you get:

[image]

Comment: thank you, that worked. I didn't know what those materials meant.

Comment: you are welcome. Please click on the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thank you.